# Alert a user to rate an application from iTunes

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone. I heard from few people that it is possible to show a alert to user @ iTunes (mobile and iTunes desktop) and get a rating of the application. Is this true and possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Appirater library for doing this: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater

Or iRate: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate

Comment: Or the lib from AskingPoint.com. A lot of setting options and it can chance in real-time, from dashboard without need for code changes or App updates.