# URL for sending a user to the app review page on device's app store

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

What's the URL to launch in order to bring the iTunes App Store to the front, and open it to show the Reviews page of an app?
I want to send my users to the "Write a Review" page.

Some other SO answers provided URLs like the one below, but it doesn't seem to work:

itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=12345678&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1

Any suggestions for a URL that'll work on iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Update: iOS 4.2 seems to have fixed this and links now open the App Store app directly rather than the review page.**

This article [Dissecting iTunes links](http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/) explains everything.

> #### Heading straight to a review form
>
> It’s also possible to send someone
>   straight to the review form for an
>   app.
>
> https://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?id=337064413&type=Purple+Software
>
> Simply replace the ID with your app’s
>   ID to create a URL for your app.
>
> On a desktop or laptop, this will take
>   you directly to the review form in
>   iTunes for the app or item. On an
>   iPhone or iPod touch, this will open
>   MobileSafari, then open iTunes or the
>   App Store app on the reviews page,
>   leaving the user only one tap away
>   from writing a review.
>
> To find out an item’s ID, right (Mac &
>   PC) or control-click (Mac) on a link
>   to the item in iTunes and select Copy
>   Link. The result will look something
>   like this.
>
> http://itunes.apple.com/au/album/dig-your-own-hole/id19605549
>
> http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/consume-mobile-isp-packages/id337064413?mt=8
>
> The ID is the number in the URL after
>   “id’.
>
> It might be worth noting that this URL
>   was created using iTunes 8. I don't
>   think there’s a way to create review
>   links in iTunes 9, so maybe this URL
>   is being phased out. Use with caution.
>
> Update: @mareMtl has provided an
>   alternative review link for apps.
>   Please note that it only works on
>   iPhone OS devices.
>
> itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=337064413

Comment: itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=337064413 is what I went with. FWIW, this works too: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=337064413. Apparently "type=Purple+Software" is important, which I was missing

Comment: Neither of these links work on iPad for me, are they iPhone only?

Comment: What happens when your app is not already on the store? how will you retrieve the appID or solve this issue?

Comment: You AppID is assigned after you create the app but before you submit your binary. So just create the app in iTunes Connect and then use that ID.

Comment: @David Dollar: while I don't own an iPad, I believe you can use a link of the form 'itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=APP_ID' for iPad-only apps. Or perhaps you meant that the link isn't linking you to an iPhone-only or Universal app when linked from your iPad?

Comment: Every time I use this URL in my iPhone (Universal) app I get the error "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". Any update to this url format?

Comment: @Kelvin : this is still working on iOS 4.3. I firstly tested using the Simulator and then nothing was working on my 4.3 environment, but on device this is working fine.

Comment: What is Purple Software :
the "type=Purple+Software" has to be there and it has to be literally "Purple Software" - it's not the name of your company, it's a codename for iPhone applications

Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app#comment9608624_3167015

Comment: Make sure the "type=Purple+Software" is in there. Doesn't work without it!

Comment: works for me on both iphone and ipad, but on devices only, not in simulator.

Comment: iOS 4.2 is just too old and this answer should be updated for relevance.

Answer (score 12):

I tried a bunch of different links, this is only one working for me on iPhone AND iPad consistently:

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8&id=YOUR_APP

Comment: How did you know that you could use this service? Is there a reference or document that explains these services and their arguments?

Comment: when i use this link i see a page that says 'your app' is only available on iPad. You can download 'your app' for your iPad in the App Store. My app is a universal app

Answer (score 9):

Check out Appirater - http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/

> Every time the user launches your app, Appirater will see if they’ve used the app for 30 days and launched it at least 15 times. If they have, they’ll be asked to rate the app, and then be taken to your app’s review page in the App Store.

Comment: You can also use [Appirater rateApp] to manually send users to the review page.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=584691809

Answer (score 0):

Am using Appirater for Rating my App

These links in AppiRater

// for ios6 or earlier

NSString *templateReviewURL = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APP_ID";

// for ios7

NSString *templateReviewURLiOS7 = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID";

These links works fine .

But takes me to "Details" page of the app .

But it should go to "Ratings and Reviews" page..

suggest me any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iTunes has a [link maker](http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/) you can use to get the URL.  Tested on my app.  It works.

Answer (score 0):

***For Requesting for rate and review to user after iOS 10.3+***

The SKStoreReviewController allows users to rate an app directly from within the app through a dialog box. The only downsite is that you can only request StoreKit to display the dialog, but can't be sure if it will.

```
import StoreKit

func requestToRate() {

     SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()

}
```