# Alert box Style in Cocos 2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos-2d , so please be gentle as this may be very noob question.

Ok now my question.

How can i implement alert box like thing in cocos 2D, with yes or no button.So Yes button calls to a method.that method opens an website link.

For example, i have seen several games ,where an alert comes to make user give review in app store..When they press yes, it takes to app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to not use the [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)? You can work with it as any UIKit application and take a look to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784248/rating-and-reviews-from-within-an-ios-app) for the rate/review library.
Anyway you can check this [article](http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/9162433577/scale9grid-for-cocos2d) which provide a custom implementation for Cocos2D.

Comment: that article is about the ccscale9sprite, not the alert (not sure why he use alert pictures, but the codes are not