# How to Unlock a feature in iPhone app with a review given by user in AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, review

I have developed an app for GMAT exam, My first exam paper is Locked.. I want to Unlock the paper whenever the user gives a `review` for my app in `appstore`. Suggest me any tutorials to do that..? When User Click on the Paper It Should Ask to give a `review`.. If he /she gives `review` I want to Unlock the Paper.

Comment: Shrikanth how do you unlock first exam paper? I mean what conditions you have to to unlock the paper

Comment: If user gives review for app Unlock the paper otherwise No.. This is my condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not way to detect this, since you do not know who the user is, there is not access to this. So you will not be able to check if the user reviewed your app.

Comment: I have seen in some of apps like "MoveTheBox" where hints are unlocked  after giving the review in appstore, So I want to use Same Technique to unlock Papers.

Comment: Well you will have to ask that developer how they did that, since you can't get the appstore account detail in your app there is no way to check wether the use really added a review. You could doe something like @Panday_Laxman said, if you redirect the user to the review page unlock the content. But you will not be able to verify that the user really submitted a review.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog that covers user app rating. http://iostipsntricks.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/how-to-get-people-to-rate-your-ios-app/

He provides links to Appirater which is a free API to handle app ratings etc.

Also, check out this post

[Rating and reviews from within an IOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784248/rating-and-reviews-from-within-an-ios-app)

From there you could just add your own methods to unlock papers.