# Rate and Review within an app take the user to app store thus leave our app - Totaly Undesired

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, review, rate

Refering questions

- [URL for sending a user to the app review page on device's app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374050/url-for-sending-a-user-to-the-app-review-page-on-devices-app-store)
- [Rating and reviews from within an IOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784248/rating-and-reviews-from-within-an-ios-app?lq=1)
- [Direct "rate in iTunes" link in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654144/direct-rate-in-itunes-link-in-my-app)

All the solutions to these question take the user to app store and leave our app. 
Is it possible to rate and review the app from within app like a web view. So that the user may not have to leave the app.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it's changed. You can use *SKStoreProductViewController* to show App Store from within an app as described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452996/540639).

Answer (score 2):

There is no alternative. Users can only rate and review through the App Store app.

Comment: is it possible to have some call back mechnism that may take the user back to our app once he/she has finsihed rating or reviewing? like the "facebook integration."???

Comment: I think it's a common complaint but as it stands, with iOS6, there is nothing like that. You can launch another app (such as App Store) but that's it--no control over it and no way to detect that is has been closed down for example. Facebook integration is a different story, it's an API. All we can hope is that some day Apple will add an API to facilitate app rating/reviews from within an app.