# Using StoreKit to push rating of apps in appstore

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

I am working on a application where I want to create my custom view for 5 star rating and this rating value I want to push on appstore for that particular application .  Is this possible?

Comment: no this is not possible, you have to open the itunes store app on iphone by passing your app id in url

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible .... You could have a look at these controls :-

[Rate View](https://github.com/dyang/DYRateView)

[Rate Stars](https://github.com/edwardinubuntu/RateStars)

Though I couldn't get your "push on appstore for that particular application" part. Could you please elaborate that ?

Comment: What I meant by "push on appstore for that particular application"  is , suppose I have rated the app 4*  and now i want to push same value for concerned application in appstore so that this rating is visible there

Comment: Its actually more simple than that in words.... It simply means you want to show the rating which you did in the app rite ? pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784248/rating-and-reviews-from-within-an-ios-app