# iTunes review URL

Tags: ios, itunes, review, app-store

An [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374050/url-for-sending-a-user-to-the-app-review-page-on-devices-app-store) discussed how to send iPhone app users to an app store review page directly

However, the link template:

https://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?id=337064413&type=Purple+Software

is no longer works in iOS 4.3. Does any know how to link user to the review page in iTunes directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=337064413"; //replace the id param's value with your App's id

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

Comment: Why its not working on iPad running iOS 5. The page is redirected to "Write a Review", but when we wrote review its not showing up in the iTuneStore? My app is in testing phase, so i am testing it in Device.

Comment: It takes time before a review shows up for an app. It does not appear immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Also works with PhoneGap/Cordova:

- "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=337064413";

or

- "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8&id=337064413"

replace the id param's value with your App's id

Answer (score 0):

Now that Cordova/PhoneGap uses the plugin [InAppBrowser](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser) for links, the correct syntax is:

```
window.open("itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scorekeepr-free/id490888743?ls=1&mt=8","_system");
```

This was tested in a real app with [Cordova-iOS 2.3.0rc2](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/) on an iPad running iOS 5.1