# Flex Mobile Open App Store for Reviews

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, app-store, flash-builder, rating

Using Flash Builder/Flex Mobile, is there a way to create a button in an iphone/ipad app that will redirect and open the app store/review section of your application?  Just trying to find a way to get users to rate my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I have a full answer now.  Thanks to Flextras and some googling.

So to make a button that will redirect to Apple Store review page for your app in Flex Mobile project..

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.net.navigateToURL;
        protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?id=(YOU APP ID GOES HERE)&type=Purple+Software");
            navigateToURL(urlReq, "_self");
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Then the button..

```
<s:Button y="720" width="65%" height="70" label="Rate this App"
   click="clickHandler(event)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a URL that you want to open, you can use [navigateToURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) to do so:

```
var myURL :String = 'URL to your iOS application';
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(myURL));
```

Then just trigger that code from the click event of a button.

Comment: Thanks!  This would work, however I am getting an error, looks like because the URL includes "&type=" in it.  This is the second part of the my question above.  You need the proper URL which I have found, see here for answer on that part [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374050/url-for-sending-a-user-to-the-app-review-page-on-devices-app-store).  Any thoughts on how to deal with the error here so I can get up and running?  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveBilodeau I'm sorry; I don't see the part of your question where you mention that using '& in the URL is causing errors.