# How do I link to the App Store reviews for an application on the iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to put a "rate/review this app" feature into my iPad app.  As described in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app), I can use code like the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=449581298&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software"]];
```

to open the App Store to the appropriate section on iPhone.

However, this method does not work on the iPad.  Is there a means of doing the same thing that still functions on the iPad?

Comment: You sure its not working on the ipad ? Did you try it on the iPad simulator or device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method I have used on my app, which is out for all iOS devices.  We have an iPad 2 that we use for testing, works great.  Perhaps it is a bug?  Have you tried upgrading the iOS?