# How to implement a "rate us" feature in a phonegap app

Tags: ios, html, cordova, app-store

I wish to add some sort of a "Write a Review" or "Rate Us" feature to my app so my customers can easily rate and review my app.

The problem is that the app is implemented using phone gap. Is it possible to implement this feature using html5-phone gap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I use navigator.notification.confirm and have it called when the user reaches a certain point or uses your app so much. Of course you need to add your own links in.

Note this snippet references other parts of my app so customize to meet your needs.

```
if (settings.core.rate_app_counter === 10) {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
    'If you enjoy using domainsicle, whould you mind taking a moment to rate it? It won\'t take more than a minute. Thanks for your support!',
    function(button) {
        // yes = 1, no = 2, later = 3
        if (button == '1') {    // Rate Now
            if (device_ios) {
                window.open('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/domainsicle-domain-name-search/id511364723?ls=1&mt=8'); // or itms://
            } else if (device_android) {
                window.open('market://details?id=<package_name>');
            } else if (device_bb){
                window.open('http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/<applicationid>');
            }

            this.core.rate_app = false;
        } else if (button == '2') { // Later
            this.core.rate_app_counter = 0;
        } else if (button == '3') { // No
            this.core.rate_app = false;
        }
    }, 'Rate domainsicle', ['Rate domainsicle', 'Remind me later', 'No Thanks']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker

Also see the section about creating a URL directly to the review page of your app.

http://www.manicgaming.com/2010/12/make-your-app-easy-to-rate/

And finally:

[App store link for "rate/review this app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app)

Comment: Whoever is changing my valid links, please stop.

Comment: It was a high rep spammer, he's now suspended for one week. Cheers for rolling back, next time you can also flag for mod attention to have the spammer dealt with earlier.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, rate this app alerts were specifically discouraged in the wwdc '11 talks.

Comment: hi, interesting. Could you explain why?

Comment: It can be an annoying user experience. I'll try to find a quote of what the apple presenter says, but the gist is that a great app will get people to rate your app regardless.

Caveat: I've bugged my friends in person to rate my app... possibly just as annoying.

Comment: ads are also annoying... but I guess the user has to leave with it if he don't want to pay the app...

Answer (score 0):

You must call `window.open` as follows

```
window.open("market://details?id=com.your.app","_system");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a plugin just for that https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate