# How to open iTunes link with inappbrowser?

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I've got inappbrowser working in my Cordova 2.8 app except that links to iTunes, like this:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.itunes.apple.com/us/app/apppname', '_blank', 'location=yes,enableViewPortScale=yes');">open</a></p>
```

do not open - can anyone help me out and explain how to fix this? (all other URL's open fine).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use **encodeURI()** method with your URL. I think it will resolve your problem

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open(encodeURI('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id58502735‌​4?mt=8&uo=4'), '_blank', 'location=yes,enableViewPortScale=yes');">Open</a>
```

**Check out this post**
[Phonegap App : External URL don't open in InApp Browser of IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569787/phonegap-app-external-url-dont-open-in-inapp-browser-of-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You should use itms-apps://www.itunes.apple.com/us/app/apppname 
It'll open the link in the iTunes app.

Comment: so you mean like itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8&uo=4

Comment: I tried this:<p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8&uo=4', '_blank', 'location=yes,enableViewPortScale=yes');">  but get this error message:webView:didFailLoadWithError - The URL can’t be shown

Comment: Check out this post from another user on StackOverflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852804/how-to-implement-a-rate-us-feature-in-a-phonegap-app

Comment: Still not getting anywhere, so please say if anyone has a solution.

Comment: Are you trying on a simulator?

Comment: Did you try it on the phone itself? Are you sure the url is correct?

Comment: Didn't work for me. Safari can't open https://itunes..., if change it to itms-apps:// the Safari even not opened.

Answer (score 0):

**The latest version of the plugin has solved this problem!**

> v 1.4