# How do I link to Play Store, so users can rate my APP?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I build an APP with phonegap. I have added a custom settings menu, with ul li tags, One of the tag needs to be a link, so users can click and go to PLay store to rate the APP. I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript: void(0);" class="rate_app">Rate App</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript: void(0);" class="exit_app">Exit APP</a></li>
</ul>




   $("li a.rate_app").on('click', function() {
    this.href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?
     id=com.project.projectXXX" //I need this link?
    });
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852804/how-to-implement-a-rate-us-feature-in-a-phonegap-app

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should point to window.location = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?
     id=com.project.projectXXX"

Comment: I think that will just open the new browser window. I want to open my APP in play store, so users can rate it and review it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it with the internal browser as following:

```
window.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.project.projectXXX', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```