# How to implement Rate App feature in iOS iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, rate, appirater

I am using Appirater to implement Rate app feature in my iPad app. There is following link in Appirater for this purpose.

itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APP_ID

But when I tap on Rat App button, it gives me an error "Could'nt connect to itunes store".
Let me clear that i had replaced APP_ID with my Apple ID before testing. I have read on some forums that this link does not work for iPad apps.

Can anyone please help?
Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [App store link for "rate/review this app"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app)

Answer (score 3):

The following works on IPhone (not on IPad):

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=APP_ID&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software
```

Just replace APP_ID with yours. Also works on Safari if you change itms-apps by http.

Original answer here: [App store link for "rate/review this app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are done with Rate feature. Appirater  works after apple approval of same app id. So you can't see review page in sandbox mode. Try by replacing just APP_ID to any released app.

Comment: my app is approved and published in appstore. By the way i have integrated iRate sdk and it worked for me on iPad.