# Open iTunes reviews tab inside the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, itunes

I know there are so many posts talking about this issue. I was trying to do this but didn't get a good result. I can open iTunes inside the app using SKStoreProductViewController, but I can't open the reviews tab directly, and I can do that with the function openURL but I have to leave my app and go to the app store.

Basically my question is if someone know about an app doing that, I would like to know if that's possible, probably you don't have a solution but I just want to know if you saw that before, so I can take a look and try to understand how to do it, probably with a tricky solution (like using UIWebView or something like that, I didnt get a good result with that).

UPDATE:

Im asking for a solution to open iTunes and reviews tab directly WITHOUT LEAVING MY APP.

or

The name of any game doing that, to understand what's doing.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to do this. Apple doesn't allow you to do that. I tried to but I failed. You just can gift your app through your own app. Thats the only thing that apple allows with their URL shemes.

Comment: Not really, the only way is leaving the app as the old method, Instead of using SKStoreProductViewController

Comment: Ya you cannot do that without leaving the app. See this for a solution if u want to leave the app 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42668756/6665075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for IOS 10.2 or lower.

Now iOS 10.3 introduces SKStoreReviewController component to rate the app directly from your app.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller

Answer (score -3):

I make this way in my app:

```
NSString *iTunesLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=%@&mt=8", ITUNES_CONNECT_APP_ID];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Comment: NO, I said that I dont want to leave my app. I want to open iTunes inside my app, same way as SKStoreProductViewController but going to reviews tab directly