# App review link not working anymore

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

Like many other developers I have a link in my app which takes the user to review my app in the app store ([App store link for "rate/review this app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app?rq=1)). In iOS7 GM and all of the betas, this link is broken (it currently takes you to a blank white screen in the app store).

I was hoping that it would be fixed by the time of the official release of iOS7 today, but that is not the case. Does anyone know if Apple will restore this link, or if they've mentioned anything about it?

Comment: Is there any information on blank white screen?

Comment: @user1673099 - What do you mean?

Comment: Can you add the image for that screen with some code?

Comment: @user1673099 - I put up a link to a question that has the code to the app review link. As for the screen shot, I don't have my phone with me right now, it's just a pure white screen, still has the toolbar and nabbers at the top and bottom.

Comment: Just try as answer & when your app Status has "Ready for sale", then you will get the your app in app store.

Comment: @user1673099 - it's already in the store, one of my users told me about it

Comment: Can you post some code for review? Tell me the app name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Old style of review url (which contains something like WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/) will not work properly on iOS7. You have to use the new format of app store url instead, something like

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID`

will work well.

You can see the issue discussion of some popular rating framework to get more information about it, maybe [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate/issues/109) or [this](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/pull/132)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not on the appstore, then you will get null response when you try to open the URL of your app right now.

Once your app will be in "Ready For Sale" status, then you will be directed to the app review page of the app.

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS9**...
Our link like this BROKE on iOS9: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=501...

But we FIXED it by change to itms:
itms://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=501...