# Why -openURL: doesn't work properly on iOS7?

Tags: ios7, url-scheme

When I call `[[UIApplication shareApplication] openURL:appStoreLink]` to open an app's rating link, it invokes the app store opening a blank page. But the same code works before iOS7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App review link not working anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889395/app-review-link-not-working-anymore)

Comment: From other's comments on the apple dev forum this might be broken atm.