# How do I open up a webpage in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, web, ios7, safari

I'm trying to figure out how to open a webpage from inside my app (not a webview). Basically the user taps a button and safari opens up with the loaded web page. I got this to work in iOS 6, but it seems that things have changed in iOS7. Below is the code that worked in iOS6.

```
-(IBAction)review:(id)sender
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                            @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appID?ls=1&mt=8"]];
}
```

Comment: You could check on this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889395/app-review-link-not-working-anymore

Comment: Your URL isn't work for iOS 7.Go through link given by Raymond.