# SKStoreProductViewController rate disabled on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

So I noticed that Apple changed SKStoreProductViewController, disabling the "Write a Review" button.
Is there any workaround or fix for this issue?

Comment: Really great solution to redirect to the store here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3167015/658604

Answer (score 14):

SKStoreProductViewController doesn't support the 'Write a review' option anymore. Why? I really don't know. It did in iOS6.

A work around could be opening the app store with a 'itms-app://'-link.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

    NSString *appURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/%@/app/id%@",
                        [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0],
                        @"YOUR_APP_ID"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];

} else {
  // your current StoreKit code    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now after iOS 10.3+**

The SKStoreReviewController allows users to rate an app directly from within the app through a dialog box. The only downsite is that you can only request StoreKit to display the dialog, but can't be sure if it will.

```
import StoreKit

func requestToRate() {
   SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793805/905517