# In-App-Rating with stars, without opening appStore

Tags: ios, app-store, storekit, rating

I want people to rate my app with stars inside the app itself, so without a SKStoreProductView (or whatever). So if they tap "rate" then there is an extra view where they can rate my app with 1 to 5 stars. How do i implement that?

thanks a lot

Comment: If there was an API for rating your app programmatically, why wouldn't you always rate your app 5 stars automatically then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible Now** after **iOS 10.3+**

The SKStoreReviewController allows users to rate an app directly from within the app through a dialog box. The only downsite is that you can only request StoreKit to display the dialog, but can't be sure if it will.

**Swift**

```
import StoreKit

func someFunction() {
   SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

-(void)someFunction {
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
}
```

**SKStoreReviewController not working**

It is only enabled after the app is downloaded from the app store.

During development, or even release build, it is grayed out.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

**Possible Now** after **iOS 10.3+**

The SKStoreReviewController allows users to rate an app directly from within the app through a dialog box. The only downsite is that you can only request StoreKit to display the dialog, but can't be sure if it will.

```
import StoreKit

func someFunction() {
   SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

Was not possible until recent iOS, there was no API.

**EDIT**:
What you see in Blek is a [GKGameCenterViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) with the GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements

Comment: No that is not true. Do you know the app "Blek"? There that is possible. But because I have not enough RP I cannot post any pictures to show what I mean :/

Comment: Put the Image somewhere else and post the URL?

Comment: It is in German, sorry for that. below the stars it says "touch to rate". So I chose 5 stars but before it was set to 0 and it is possible to choose any other amount of stars

Comment: Are you sure this rating then goes into the App Store? I did another check but can't find an API for that. Or subclass the SKStoreProductView?

Comment: Well of course I cannot be completely sure, that's why I contacted Kunabi-Brothers to tell me whether the rating is for the appStore or maybe the gameCenter, that is possible as well. I will keep you up to date.  But thanks for your help for now. :)

Comment: well the developers are not responding, so I guess they won't anymore. I also found this feature in "Boost 2" and "Flappy Bird". So I think it this rating is just referring to the gameCenter. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @LiGe even thou the answer was probably not to your taste, i'd kindly invite you to accept it by using the green check mark down below the rating.