# Is there any default API which shows a rating alert in iOS?

Tags: ios, rate, alertview

All,

I would like to show an alert which allows user to rate my app. I got the following two link. However this did not answer whether any API available to show an alert.

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-add-write-a-review-rate-us-feature-to-your-app/

[App store link for "rate/review this app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app)

Do i need to show my own alert and redirect user to appstore link. Or any other alternative methods available so that user can rate my app within application ?

Regards,

Bhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official Apple API to show "rate this app" dialogs. You need to implement that yourself or use one of the many third party frameworks. Here are some examples:

- [iRate by Nick Lockwood](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)
- [Appirater by Arash Payan](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater)
- [UAAppReviewManager by Matt Coneybeare](https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAAppReviewManager)

You should also consider that users don't want to see that alert pop up most of the times. There was a lot of discussion in the iOS developer community over the last year about that topic. Do some research and think how you can provide a "rate this app" link in the least intrusive way possible!

Answer (score 1):

This has now changed as there is the SKStoreReviewController.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller