# iOS App - include rating-link - choose type of App ID

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm close to submitting an app to the App Store and would like to include a rating-link in the first published version to present the user an easy way to rate the app or write a review.

So first I generated a new app via iTunes Connect without any further steps - just an empty hull. Inside the app there is an area named “App-Information” with a link at the bottom named “Show in App Store”. Of course this link is not active, because the app is not “Ready for Sale” at this time. But perhaps this link can be modified with GET-Parameters for example, to accomplish this task once the app is ready for sale.
Do you know how I can build an appropriate link for rating/writing reviews before the app is approved?

Then I don't know for sure whether to choose a wildcard App ID or not for a created app. Is the only criterion the need of using a service expecting an explicit App ID? For example, if I would like to store app related data inside iCloud then I would create and choose an explicit ID, and otherwise I also can use an already existing wildcard ID?

And can I first create an App with a wildcard App ID and choose an explicit App ID later when needed? I think I don’t understand the need or advantage of wildcard IDs in common, because a new App ID (explicit or not) is created within a minute with very little effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App store link for "rate/review this app"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app)

Comment: You are asking two completely different questions here. Please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID
```

For versions lower than iOS 7 use the old one:

```
itmsapps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=YOUR_APP_ID
```

in code

```
define YOUR_APP_STORE_ID 545174222 //Change this one to your ID

    static NSString *const iOS7AppStoreURLFormat = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%d";
    static NSString *const iOSAppStoreURLFormat = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%d"

    [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0f)? iOS7AppStoreURLFormat: iOSAppStoreURLFormat, YOUR_APP_STORE_ID]]; // Would contain the right link
```