# How to link to app reviews in App Store in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

*Of course I know about the new guidelines and `SKStoreReviewController` to prompt users for reviews. But this is not about asking for new review but about quickly accessing reviews of different apps.*

**The Problem:**

Previously I used the following format to link from an iOS App directly to the reviews tab of an app in the App Store:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=APP_ID&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&type=Purple+Software&mt=8
```

This worked fine, but in iOS 11 it shows just an empty page within the App Store app. The obvious reason is, that in iOS 11 the app pages do not have a Review Tab anymore, but the reviews are located under the app description and screenshots.

So using the following format still brings the user to the apps store page but one has to manually scroll down to the review.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID
```

This works of course but one has to scroll down to the reviews manually. Is it still some how possible to directly link to the review section (just like using an anchor on a normal HTML page)?

Comment: This is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45710637

Comment: No, it's not :-) I posted the linked answer to point out, that the previous methods do not work anymore. However the question here is, if there are new methods to still directly link to the review...

Answer (score 19):

This link format will work in iOS 11:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-u/id123456789?action=write-review
```

It also compatible with iOS 10.3.

The older versions I didn't test.

There is a country/region abbreviation ‘`us`’ in the URL. But it doesn't matter. It will always open the app store in the current region. No need to change it. Without these two letters, it can’t find your app.

Comment: `itunes-u` in path is the name of the app?

Comment: The only thing you have to change is the app id. Replace 123456789 with your app id.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer to use other answer by 132206. Also you didn't reply my question. And the is a [documented way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) of creating review links in iOS 11.

Answer (score 8):

Add &action=write-review to the end of the url.

http link:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appName/id1234567?mt=8&action=write-review

itms link:
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appName/id1234567?action=write-review

Update:
You'll need a country code and appName for this to work, looks like they can be anything as it's not actually used.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in iOS 11. If you leave off everything after the ? including the ? then you get to the App Store page, but not directly to the review entry screen.

Comment: ensure you have an app name and country code (they can be anything).

Comment: So country code is countryCode=dummy and appName is appName=dummy?

Comment: countryCode needs to be 2 characters eg. xx

Answer (score 8):

Actually my app (iOS 11) is working with this link :

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id{appStoreId}?action=write-review`

If you are using iRate library you can override the link :

`iRate.sharedInstance().ratingsURL = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id{appStoreId}?action=write-review")`

Comment: This is the best answer without unnecessary country or app name info