# SKStore​Review​Controller: How to get written reviews?

Tags: ios, app-store, skstorereviewcontroller

At first `SKStore​Review​Controller` looks great: An easy and standardized way to ask users for a review. However `SKStore​Review​Controller` only allows the user to **rate the** app by giving it 1 to 5 stars. But am I supposed to engage the user to leave a **written review** in the store? Is this possible using `SKStore​Review​Controller` as well?

Or do I have to do this manually, e.g. by prompting something like *"Thanks for rating the App, would you like to write a review as well"*? I doubt that many users would be happy to perform another action after they just rated the app...

Wouldn't prompting for a written review would conflict with Apples guidelines not to prompt the user without using `SKStore​Review​Controller`?

Answer (score 0):

Users cannot add a review though `SKStoreReviewController`.

It is also not possible for you to know if your `requestReview()` call actually resulted in a rate alert being presented. If the user has already rated the app recently, `requestReview()` will silently fail. Because of this, it is not advised to perform UI changes relying on the existence of an `SKStoreReviewController`.

I believe the suggested method for letting users *review* your app is to add a dedicated "Review App" button that [deep links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app) to your app in the App Store. This should be prompted by the user, and not the product of an alert.

Comment: There are ways to detect if rating window has been presented.

Answer (score 0):

> To automatically open a page on which users can write a review in the App Store, append the query parameter action=write-review to your product URL.