# Understanding simple code in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I found an answer to implement a link to get rated on the app store ([App store link for "rate/review this app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app)). Answer is:

```
let appID = "Your App ID on App Store"
let urlStr = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appID)" // 
(Option 1) Open App Page    
let urlStr = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/viewContentsUserReviews?
id=\(appID)" // (Option 2) Open App Review Tab


if let url = URL(string: urlStr), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) 
{
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: 
nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
}
```

I am having trouble understanding how to implement this. Particularly I don't understand how the if statement will take the user to the app store.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read official doc's. Atleast you need to write code instead of copy past for better underatanding

Comment: Don't you understand what `UIApplication.shared.open(url` means? Swift/APIs are verbose to be easily understandable.

Comment: I found Sh_Kahn's answer really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**The first part**

```
let appID = "Your App ID on App Store"
let urlStr = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appID)" // 
(Option 1) Open App Page    
let urlStr = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/viewContentsUserReviews?
id=\(appID)" // (Option 2) Open App Review Tab
```

gets the url of your app in itunes review section so user can write a review

**The second part**

```
if let url = URL(string: urlStr), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
```

checks if the url is valid and can be opened by `application.shared` if ok it's check the needed function according to the current version.
Actually system know that the app needs to open the url , when it executes the statement , look at `open`

```
  UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
```

Or

```
  UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

Comment: Even though now it seems obvious I was really not getting it.  This was really helpful. Thanks, really.

Answer (score 0):

you are opening url with itms-apps:// scheme. So system itself knows what app should handle this.