# IOS redirect from app to store

Tags: ios, applet, app-store, rate

I've developing ios apps for about 2 years, my projects has more apps section to cross-promo my apps, I used following url pattern to redirect to them

```
string link = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=" + id;
```

Recently I've tested this link and fount **"Cannot Connect to App Store"**

1. Why its stop working?
2. Where I find related info where Apple decided to change syntaxes and stop supporting old one
3. As a solution I found that [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app) is working now, so I id value form server, now I am planning to use regex to remove old part and replace it with working one

P.S. Why Apple doing it

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would anyone here know why Apple does anything?

Comment: @Paulw11I wrote that because its very big pain, I can't get why someone decide to not support old style of links. Is it hard to support backward compatibility? I don't think so

Comment: You should really use `SKStoreProductViewController` anyway. It has been available since iOS 6 and you wouldn't have any issues with urls plus it gives a better user experience