# Rate app button on my iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes-store

On my iOS app, I need to add a button "Rate this app"..

I'm confused about the link to itunes: How can I know my APP_ID.

The application is not yet on the store but I'm ready for publication (I have everything that I need)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011246/alert-a-user-to-rate-an-application-from-itunes/3011331#3011331

Comment: If you have set up the metadata for your app in iTunesConnect then it should show you your app ID. If you click on More -> About This App you will find what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You must have prepared your app for submission on https://itunesconnect.apple.com. If not, please go ahead.

2) Then, it generates "Apple Id". That is an automatically generated ID assigned to your app.

This "Apple Id" is your APP_ID.

You can ses this(Apple Id) under "General App Information" section below the "App Icon".

Answer (score 4):

In the iTunes connect portal, navigate to My Apps and then to the version of the app you are about to release. In the tabs above, click "More" and then View on App Store. The resulting page displayed will the url of this app (it will navigate to a broken page right now since your app hasn't been released yet).

For future reference, the iTunes url format of any app submitted is as follows:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/<STORE_ID>/app/id<APPLE_ID>
```

where,

STORE_ID is the store code where you are releasing the app (*us* by default)
APPLE_ID is the Apple ID of your app (can be found both on *iTunes Connect -> Apps ->  -> More -> About this App* **AND** on the details page for your app)

Sample:

store: US :: Apple ID: 869231055

resulting URL:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id869231055

Comment: This just goes to the app page, and the user still has to scroll and tap the rating. Is there a shortcut here?